# Can I store socket.io socket in redux store? (and call its functions)

Tags: node.js, redux, socket.io

I am trying to store a socket created for the client in App.js in my Redux store? I am not sure if this is even a good idea or not, but I want to be able to access the same socket in multiple components, so I thought I could just do it like I did with other objects.

Howerever, the things I stored until now in my redux store are strictly objects with fields in them, I have never stored an object that had functions.

When I try to call a function of the stored socket, I get:
TypeError: this.props.socket.emit is not a function.

Which I guess means that I can't store class entities using Redux. Is this correct?

What would be the right solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best method to do something like this would be to isolate all code that deals with sockets and expose only those functions that your components call (something like `socket.send(message: string)` to send message etc).

Don't worry about `import`ing the same module/file again and again, as no matter how many times you import/require it, the same instance is returned. So it's safe to isolate the socket functions and import them wherever needed.

Also, Redux is a state management library, therefore please don't expect it to handle functions and other advanced functionality.

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://redux.js.org/faq/code-structure#where-should-websockets-and-other-persistent-connections-live) Middleware are the right place for persistent connections like websockets or socket.io socket in a Redux app, for several reasons:

- Middleware exist for the lifetime of the application
- Like with the store itself, you probably only need a single instance of a given connection that the whole app can use
- Middleware can see all dispatched actions and dispatch actions themselves. This means a middleware can take dispatched actions and turn those into messages sent over the websocket, and dispatch new actions when a message is received over the websocket.
- A websocket connection instance isn't serializable, so it doesn't belong in the store state itself

These are good links to help you get started:

- https://wanago.io/2021/12/20/redux-middleware-websockets/
- https://www.taniarascia.com/websockets-in-redux/